# How to make a TileOverlay cover the text of the covered map?

Tags: android, android-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have an app that use the old google map API and add a layer over the map to display a more precise map of my own over the map.

I'm trying to do this in the API v2 using the TileOverlay but the text of the google map are displayed over my tiles.

Here are 2 screenshots, one with the map, and one with the map with an overlay (just based on the API demo)
I tried to add a big Z-Index to the tiles without any results.

Is there any way to really cover the map with custom tiles ?

[image: Google Map] [image: Google Map with moon overlay]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you keep seeing the labels, is that in google maps v2 the labels are rendered locally instead of being part of tile bitmaps. The benefit of this, is that you can rotate the map and still have the labels without rotation for easy reading.

**Solution**

The only solution I know so far is to disable the map base layer using `setMapType(MAP_TYPE_NONE)`. However, this may have the undesireble effect of also disabling parts of the map that are not being covered by your overlay.

Regards.

Comment: setMapType(MAP_TYPE_NONE) was in the API examples, but I need to add an overlay over the map just in some places.
It seems I'll have to find a workaround with another layer over the map API :-(